# Javascript RegExp test class name

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to test classnames of different nodes in event delegation method I am using :

the test case I am using is

```
   function clickHandler(e){
        var evt = e || window.event;
        target = evt.target || evt.srcElement, 
        cls = target.className,id = target.id;

       if(/\bcell\b/i.test(cls)){
          //perform some action is node having classname cell is clicked 
       }
   }
```

but this particular test is match for nodes with classname `.cell` as well as `.cell-validation-text`.

The above test return true for both these nodes. How can i modify my regExp so as my above test **returns true** only for **node having class .cell** and **false for .cell-validation text**

Comment: Don't do it this way. Instead, put different handlers on different elements.

Comment: @torazaburo...sir...can you please illustrate this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/\bcell(\s|$)/
```

`\s` matches any whitespace character

`$` matches the end of the string

EDIT: assuming you don't want to match "xxx-cell" either:

```
/(^|\s)cell(\s|$)/
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of anchors and alternation operator `|`

```
function clickHandler(e){
    var evt = e || window.event,
    target = evt.target || evt.srcElement, 
    cls = target.className,id = target.id;
    if(/\bcell(\s|$)/i.test(cls)){
       //perform some action is node having classname cell is clicked 
    }
}
```

But it would be better if you did something like

```
if(cls.split(" ").indexOf("cell") > -1){

}
```